# GRASS Hough transform issue

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-processing, hough-transform

Via GRASS
I installed the Hough transform.
I start the Hough transform but it doesn't give any rendering time and the rendering doesn't finish.

[image: İmage processing screen shot]

The image I used;
(Canny edge detection applied image)
[QGIS Hough Transform Error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/413241/194149)

Comment: please don't just repost earlier questions

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works